# Геттер и сеттер просто по имени переменной класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть такой себе простой класс для многопоточной работы с глобальными переменными:

```
/* Global Secured Variable */
template <class T>
class GSV{
    T value;
    HANDLE mutex;
public:
    GSV(){mutex = CreateMutexA(0, false, 0);}
    ~GSV(){CloseHandle(mutex);}
    T get(){
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        T val = value;
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        return val;
    }
    void set(T val){
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        value = val;
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    }
};
```

То есть класс управляет всего одним значением, которое нужно задавать и читать. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы обращение к переменной класса, например `GSV<string> Var;`, происходило просто по её имени `Var` - то есть без `Var.get()`? С сеттером вроде всё понятно - перегрузить оператор =, а вот как геттер сделать "визуально простым" чё-т не пойму (если это вообще возможно).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте оператор приведения к типу.

```
template <class T>
class GSV{
...
  operator T() { return get(); }
```

Либо перегружайте `T& operator*()` и `T* operator->()` как у умных указателей.
Для поддержки присваивания надо будет написать класс прокси, т.е.

```
struct Proxy {
   void operator=(T);
   operator T();
};
Proxy operator*();
```

Comment: Но важно помнить, что если определить и оператор приведения, и конструктор копирования как не explicit, то при вызове произойдет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: @Abyx, ОК, работает! А со структурами так можно? В смысле если в качестве T будет структура? Не получается получить доступ к полям структуры...

Comment: @Abyx, и кстати, у `GSV<string> Var` нет функций `std::string` через точку если использовать `operator T()`. Это как-то решается?

Comment: @Abyx, не подскажете как это сделать - вернуть из оператора интерфейс того же `std::string` или любого кастомного класса?

Comment: @Iceman, посмотрите какие методы реализованы у умных указателей. std::shared_ptr, например. Но только имейте ввиду что переопределяя операторы приведения типа, стрелку и звездочку, вы применяете довольно хитрые приемы для несложной задачи. Вообщем подумайте, [стоит ли оно того](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, спасибо за совет! Не буду заморачиваться - ограничусь примитивами типа `bool`, `int` и т.п. используя данный класс.